# Error Opening MXD - The last successfully loaded component was: esriGeometry.ProjectedCoordinateSystem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mxd

Why are we getting this error when trying to open some MXD files?

Myself and another coworker are getting this same error when opening several MXDs  (see Error Message 1 below). We have all verified we are on ArcMap 10.4.1. The person who created the MXD also verified they are on 10.4.1 (usually there is no problem opening other MXDs she creates). This is only happening to 2 out of 5 people in the office. This error is also different than the normal error message regarding opening an MXD saved with a newer version (see Error Message 2 below for the normal error message).

[image: Error Message 1]

[image: Error Message 2]

Edit: Per response to original question I tried MXD doctor on the original and a copy on the server. I also backed up to local machine and tried it on that. All attempts resulted in the same error message below.

[image: MXD Doctor Result]

Comment: In your Programs - ArcGIS folder you will find an application called MXD Doctor which will repair all kinds of errors with MXDs.  What happens if you run MXD Doctor on your MXD?  My guess would be that one of your cooworkers has a corrupted MXD as a template from which other MXDs are being generated from.

Comment: Please provide errors as text rather than just pictures so that they can be read easily on all devices and become available to future searches.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem with a colleague and I both running 10.5.1. I couldn't open their MXDs or drag and drop MPKs into ArcMAP. Still not sure what the problem is but work around was create MPK and use ArcToolbox to unpack MPK file which created 2 folders to assist with backwards compatibility. Folders v10 & v105 were created with the MXD in v105 not working and the one unpacked to v10 opening with no issues. Hope this helps people who need a quick work around.
This was an odd error as others in my organisation also had issues opening the original MPK and MXD. Would be curious if anyone else has an explanation for this.

[image: Folder structure]